# Two Java Applications behave differently when query from DB

Tags: java, resultset, oracle19c

I have two Java applications running on the same server, fetching data from the same Oracle DB. The data is updated in real-time. The first application reads directly from the updated tables, while the second reads data from an Oracle view, fetching data from those tables. Both applications bring data through threads running periodically at a 250 milliseconds interval. If the first application fetches 10 records, the second should also fetch 10 records, but what happens is the first fetches 10 while the other fetches 4, why this happened?

here's the query of the first App:

```
select  T.Id,   
    T.Index_Name,
    T.xIndex,
    T.NetChange,
    T.PrcntChange,
    T.to_char(IDXM_RCV_DT+NUMTODSINTERVAL(3,'HOUR') ,'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3') local_time ,
    T.TradeVolume,
    T.TradeValue,
    T.TodayInitIndex,
    T.IndexHigh,
    T.IndexLow,
    T.YestCloseIndex,
    T.T.YestCloseAdjusted, 
    T.ChangeDir,
    I.IDXM_LI_TOT_TRAD_SYM totalSym,
    I.IDXM_LI_TOT_TRAD_NB||'' totalTrades,
    I.IDXM_LI_TOT_TRAD_QTY||'' totalQty,
    I.IDXM_LI_TOT_TRAD_VAL||'' totalValue
    from 
      Indices T, 
      tipowner.idxm I
    where 
      I.IDXM_IDX_ID=T.id 
      AND T.IDXM_RCV_DT > (to_timestamp('2023/08/03 16:47:23.496','YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3')-(3/24))
```

Here's the view definition:

> 

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW vw_l_mkt_index (
  market,
  name_en,
  name_ar,
  msg_timestamp,
  status,
  index_value,
  change,
  change_percent,
  trades_count,
  traded_symbols,
  traded_value,
  traded_volume,
  rising_symbols,
  dropping_symbols,
  flat_symbols,
  open_time,
  close_time
) AS
SELECT /*+ INDEX(IDXM IX_IDXM_IDX_ID_RECV_DT) INDEX(T IX_TADAWUL_INDICES_TS) */
    I.IDXM_IDX_ID AS MARKET,
    I.IDXM_DESC AS NAME_EN,
    I.IDXM_ADESC AS NAME_AR,to_timestamp(to_char(I.IDXM_RCV_DT+NUMTODSINTERVAL(3,'HOUR'),'dd.mm.yy HH24:MI:SS.FF3'), 'dd.mm.yy HH24:MI:SS.FF3') AS MSG_TIMESTAMP,
    P.MKT_STATUS AS STATUS,
    T.XINDEX AS INDEX_VALUE,
    DECODE(T.CHANGEDIR, '-', (T.NETCHANGE * -1), T.NETCHANGE)AS CHANGE,
    DECODE(T.CHANGEDIR, '-', (T.PRCNTCHANGE * -1), T.PRCNTCHANGE) AS CHANGE_PERCENT,
    I.IDXM_LI_TOT_TRAD_NB || '' AS TRADES_COUNT,
    I.IDXM_LI_TOT_TRAD_SYM AS TRADED_SYMBOLS,
    I.IDXM_LI_TOT_TRAD_QTY || '' AS TRADED_VOLUME,
    I.IDXM_LI_TOT_TRAD_VAL || '' AS TRADED_VALUE,
    I.IDXM_LI_ADV_TRAD_SYM AS RISING_SYMBOLS,
    I.IDXM_LI_DEC_TRAD_SYM AS DROPPING_SYMBOLS,
    I.IDXM_LI_UNC_TRAD_SYM AS FLAT_SYMBOLS,
    TO_CHAR(M.MK_FROM, 'HH24:MI:SS') AS OPEN_TIME,
    TO_CHAR(M.MK_TO, 'HH24:MI:SS') AS CLOSE_TIME
  FROM IDXM I, INDICES T, PARAM P, MARKET M
  WHERE IDXM.IDXM_IDX_ID = T.ID
    AND M.MK_CODE (+)= IDXM.IDXM_IDX_ID
    AND IDXM.IDXM_IDX_ID <> 'NOMU'
```

both of them use the same Java version, the same driver.

Comment: Your oracle views are not probably refreshed.   Are they set to be refreshed automatically or manually

Comment: @ManKeer Could you provide both queries the "main" one and the view one? The definition of the view? And any relevant Java code? Thanks

Comment: Also, provide any connection details for each application, and anything about how/when the data is being updated. Is the data also *updated* by the first application?

Comment: Your view selects from some tables that your query does not use.
What happens when you execute both the query and a select from the view manually?

You can even do a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ( <your query> ) UNION ALL SELECT COUNT(*) FROM vw_l_mkt_index` manually to verify if they return the same number of lines at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I posted my first answer before you added the definition for the view, so I will edit it. Taking into consideration the queries are on different tables, based on what data you have it's normal to get different sets of results, so you need to make a thorough analysis on the data.

Comment: _I posted my first answer before you added the definition for the view, so I will edit it._ Pardon me, but I did not see another answer from you. In any case, your "answer" is a comment and not an answer (in my opinion). I also see that you have the [Informed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2600/informed?userid=4448293) badge which means you should know that you should not post a comment as an answer.